# Where to write FROM in IF?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've already written the function, I'm trying to use `FROM` within an `IF` statement. The code below is written within a function.

```
IF myParameter IN (SELECT id FROM myTable) AND myTable.myType='Type A' THEN
```

Of course, it gives an error

> Unknown table 'myTable'

when trying to execute the function.

EDIT: myParameter is an INT

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
IF myParameter IN (SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE myTable.myType = 'Type A') THEN
```

That is, move the condition to the subquery.

Comment: In MySQL there are keyword THEN outside CASE WHEN ? Surprised

Comment: @DmitryReutov . . . The OP specifies that this is inside a function.  `IF` statements are supported in programming blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I'd use `EXISTS` for this kind of check:

`IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = myParameter AND myType='Type A') THEN`

`EXISTS` will stop processing at the first match, and despite requiring a SELECT for syntax reasons, doesn't actually create an intermediate result; `IN` generally processes the entire query within it, formulates a result set, and then checks the left hand argument of the `IN` against potentially everything in that result (it probably stops at the first match two, but it still had to assemble the entire result).

If `myparameter` is filtering on the table's primary key, it probably will not make much of a difference in this case; but it something to keep in mind in the more general sense.